# Accessing Parquet files form Teiid

Tags: parquet, teiid, wildfly-11

Can Teiid be used to access parquet files stored in external directory (out side the web container) in Wildfly web application? Appreciate any help on this

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can here is the translator [1] the data can be in a file, hdfs or S3 is done as part of [2]. You can see an example in WildFly here [3].

it looks like we have not added in the Teiid SpringBoot, but should be simple enough to add if you are using that.

[1] http://teiid.github.io/teiid-documents/master/content/reference/r_parquet-translator.html

[2] https://issues.redhat.com/browse/TEIID-4594

[3] https://github.com/teiid/teiid/blob/master/wildfly/test-integration/common/src/test/java/org/teiid/arquillian/IntegrationTestParquet.java

Comment: I am getting an error when configuring the resource adapter, is there a way I can share the cli commands and error that I am getting.

Comment: when configuring the file resource adapter I am getting the following error, Can you let me know what could be the reason?.  Failure: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.ra.deployment.\"org.jboss.teiid.resource-adapter.file:main_file\"" => "WFLYJCA0046: Failed to start RA deployment [file]
    Caused by: org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.DeployException: IJ020060: Unable to inject: org.teiid.resource.adapter.file.FileManagedConnectionFactory property: Parentdirectory value: C:\\development\\wild
fly-19.1.0.Final/teiidfiles"}}

Comment: Is `C:\\development\\wild fly-19.1.0.Final/teiidfiles` accessible from your wildfly server? to define the resource adapter you can directly edit the `standalone-teiid.xml` file and add resource adapater there.